# With mmap() how can dynamically sized structures be created

Tags: c, dynamic, struct, mmap

Hi I have the following scenario

```
#define CONSTANT 10

struct structA{
    int var1;
    int var2[CONSTANT];
};

main(){
    structA *varA = NULL;
    int i;

    /* some C code */


    varA = mmap(0,..);
    for(i = 0; i < CONSTANT; i++){
        varA.var2[i] = /* C code */ ;
    }

    /* C code */

}
```

Here the number of elements in `var2` array of `structA` is constant and hence the `varA.var2[i]` can be directly referenced . But If the number `CONSTANT` is to be determined dynamically during runtime , how should the structure definition be modified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number CONSTANT cannot be determined dynamically at runtime, since it affects the structure size.

The usual trick for what you're trying to do (I'm not sure if it's strictly valid C but it's very common) is to create

```
struct structA{
    int var1;
    int var2[0];
};
```

and when you map or allocate, allocate `(sizeof(structA) + sizeof(int) * CONSTANT)` bytes.

Comment: It's worth noting it's a [GNU extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html).

Answer (score 3):

The cleanest way would be to use a C99 flexible array member:

```
struct structA{
    int var1;
    int var2[];
};
```

Then you can just `mmap(NULL, sizeof(int) * (num + 1), ...)`. Just be careful with flexible array members, `sizeof` behaves funny with them (doesn't include their size).

If you can't / won't use a flexible array member, you can use a pointer instead of an array and `mmap` memory separately for it.

Answer (score 2):

The most common way to do this is:

```
struct structA{
    int var1;
    int var2[1];
};
```

It's not really an array with a single element, because you allocate more memory than the size of a `structA`.